# React Draggle Components alignment issue using react-draggable

Tags: reactjs, draggable

I am using react-draggable to create draggable components. I have multiple Draggable components in the same parent div. But if I set the default coordinates to 0,0 they do not come on top of each other, instead subsequent components' coordinates get off set by previous Draggable components size

```
import React from "react";
import Draggable from "react-draggable";

const DraggableComponent = ({ id, defaultPosition }) => {
  return (
    <Draggable defaultPosition={defaultPosition} grid={[1, 1]}>
      <div
        className="draggable-component"
        style={{ width: "100px", height: "50px", border: "1px solid black" }}
      >
        Draggable {id}
      </div>
    </Draggable>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="parent-container">
      <DraggableComponent id={1} defaultPosition={{ x: 10, y: 10 }} />
      <DraggableComponent id={2} defaultPosition={{ x: 10, y: 10 }} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image]

How can I have multiple draggable components with